# Why not draw a custom font with lines and/or polygons?

Tags: rendering, performance, fonts, spritefont

Reasons/advantages I see:

1. More flexible procedural animation.
2. Completely custom font.
3. Performance (no texturing or high-poly)?
4. No assets (unless data-driven).
5. Multi-resolution compared to sprite fonts / sprites.

Downsides I see:

1. Effort and time to define every character.
2. Effort and time to implement the general code.
3. Future localization pain.

Example: https://youtu.be/Tz7L-92Bo-M?t=2m13s

1. Is this unreasonable and why?
2. Will I get a rendering performance win compared to sprite fonts on common multi-core mobile devices?

Comment: If you're not a font designer, you'll have trouble making a good font. It's an extremely subtle art.

Comment: In your example video, the "custom font" used is extremely simple; it matches the look and feel of that game pretty well, but would look horribly out of place in a lot of other games.

Comment: Future localization is an epic nightmare if you want to support, say, Asian languages. If you just want to use English, not as big of a deal.

Answer (score 2):

Because it's a lot of effort for very little gain. Ignoring for the moment the difficulty of creating a nice, atheistically-pleasing collection of glyphs in the first place, looking at your list of "pros:"

> More flexible procedural animation.

This depends on the kind of animation you're talking about. There's really no advantage here if you're just moving the text around, rotating it, scaling it, making it go in sine wave patterns, et cetera. If you want to deform the actual glyphs in some interesting and unusual way, then sure.

> Completely custom font.

Not sure why this is an advantage over using an existing, time-tested font.

> Performance (no texturing or high-poly)?

Probably not actually an advantage; probably either a wash, or a net loss. Rendering text via quads is *really* cheap. Rendering it via a bunch of lines or triangles converted from some likely vector-based description of glyphs? Not so much.

> No assets (unless data-driven).

Not really. You have to store the description of your custom collection of lines/vertices that represent the glyphs somewhere. This is not really any different from storing an existing font (TrueType, et cetera) or pre-rendered sprite texture.

> Multi-resolution compared to sprite fonts / sprites

Compared to sprites, perhaps, but only if you're storing the font glyphs in a vectorized format... which is sort of what existing font formats store things as. You can achieve the same thing by using font rendering APIs like FreeType or CoreText to render text to textures on the fly; this can be done very fast and supports not only a effectively infinite range of resolutions and scales but all the other really nice stuff like kerning and ligatures that those APIs provide.

---

On the other hand, every single one of your cons is pretty spot on. So basically, it's a ton of work, and in most cases all the gains you'd realize you could also realize by not completely pre-baking your sprite fonts (instead using FreeType/CoreText/et cetera).